# Is it possible to show a menu in a view as buttons?

Tags: views, 8

I'm trying to build a page with a quick menu. Now I've created a menu by the regular way and I've shown this on the place i wanted. Now due to the way my site currently looks, this is very out of the shape I wanted it to be.

Now my question is: Is it possible to show my menu items as a view and decorate them with a button (and if possible an icon from the FontAwesome library)?

My idea would look something like this, with the blue things as buttons creating for every menu item:

[image]

A module or a work around would both be fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_attributes
you can add a css classes to each menu item so that you can theme it as needed.

Comment: I think this will work out for me, thankyou.